# typeerror (0 graphql _1.is definition node) is not a function

Tags: url, graphql, routes, apollo-server

I'm reading while coding a book(Pro MERN Stack 2nd Edition) and I get the error:

`typeerror (0 graphql _1.is definition node) is not a function`

in my GitCMD.
[Click here to see the error in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAj8B.png)

I have tried [this](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), from another StackOverflow error but since Im using the `apollo-server-express` I think is kind of different.

Also tried installing older and newer package versions of the following:

```
"apollo-server-express": "^3.11.1"
```

and

```
"graphql": "^0.13.2",
```

The code looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
let aboutMessage = "Issue Tracker API v1.0";

const typeDefs = `
    type Query {
        about: String!
    }
    type Mutation {
        setAboutMessage(message: String!): String
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        about: ()=> aboutMessage,
    },
    Mutation: { 
        setAboutMessage,       
    },
};

function setAboutMessage(_, { message }) {
    return aboutMessage = message;
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App started on port 3000');
});
```

this part alone:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App started on port 3000');
});
```

worked perfectly fine, but since I added the rest of it, it returns me the error :/

Answer (score 0):

I updated my graphql to `"graphql": "^16.6.0"` and I got a different error: `` You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.applyMiddleware() `` so for that I needed to create an **Async function**, and inside the function I needed the name for my new server, the typeDefs, resolvers and then the `await myserver.start():`
and then the
`myserver.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });` I dont know if thats well explained but here are the changes I made for the code to work:

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
let aboutMessage = "Issue Tracker API v1.0";

const typeDefs = `
    type Query {
        about: String!
    }
    type Mutation {
        setAboutMessage(message: String!): String
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        about: ()=> aboutMessage,
    },
    Mutation: { 
        setAboutMessage,       
    },
};

function setAboutMessage(_, { message }) {
    return aboutMessage = message;
}

async function startServer(){
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
    });
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
}
startServer();

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App started on port 3000');
});
```

I didnt figured out on my own actually, I saw a post in Qiita about the same issue: [Qiita same error URL](https://qiita.com/kajima/items/2405a44a2c6f14de7919).